# What's the relation between Shiva and Maa Lakshmi?

Tags: shiva, lakshmi

I am asking this because it happened that I have noticed the mention of one portion of Sri Sukta dedicated to Maa Lakshmi, into a complete full Rudra Path chant (namakam and chamakam together); also I have noticed the mention of Maa Lakshmi in a final shloka of the Shiva Tandava Stotram and in the Maa Lakshmi Sri Sukta there is also God Shiva mentioned. Hence I was wondering what is the link, history, or and relation between Goddess Maa Lakshmi and God Shiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the answer to another question (here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34175/22667)

I have found a hint to answer to my own still unanswered question here above:

The Varaha-Purana says in chapter 25

```
purusho vishnur iti ukto shivo vaa naamatah smritah/avyaktam tu umaa devi shrir vaa padmanivekshanaa//
```

meaning : The Primal Being is known as Vishnu or Shiva in Manifest form and is the lotus-eyed Umaa or Shri (Lakshmi) in the Unmanifest form.

Considering this from Varaha Purana and also considering what Shiva Samhita says about Maa Lakshmi being the beautiful manifestation of an excess of Sattva in the Aavidya whose Intelligence is called Vishnu.

Considering that
The Vishnu-Puraana says:

matto abhinnaatmaanam drashtum arhasi samkara/yo aham sa tvam jagat cha idam sdeva-asura-manusham/avidya-mohitaatmaanam purushaa vinnadarshinah//(48).

Here Sri Vishnu is saying to Sri Shiva : I and You are one and the same in the essence--the All pervading one residing in all gods, demons and men.Only the persons deluded by ignorance sees us differently.

I shall consider Durga, Lakshmi and Saraswaati as excesses of Tama, Sattva and Raja Gunas coming from Aavidya respectively, hence the link role of them in regards of Shiva is the same of a set of diverses representations of the Shakti, respectively to Ishwara. Naarayana with Lakshmi, Uma Parvati with Shiva, Saraswaati with Brahma. Each of them representing the qualities or Gunas.

The Sattvic Guna in order to defeat an excess of Tama is needed to advance in the Yogic path.

Henceforth we find in the Chamakam of Rudra Path the invocation of that Lakshmi who can help us to reach Moksha, in the same way Lakshmi may grant this prosperity of yoga [Samadhi and Moksha are the real Treasure granted by Lakshmi as the meaning of Lakshmi it indicates among many shlokas in the Vedas and other scriptures] to whom recites Shiva Tandava Stotram, or listen to it and so Sri Sukta of Her contains a link to Shiva as the God of All and the Perfect Yogi.

Please, because I am only a student, feel free to correct me by emendating any mistakes.
Let's help each others.

Footnote:

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44111/22667

This is my associated new question which is a Asking for a Research which I also posted as an answer under others Q&A.

That is a partial answer to other Questions inherent Sects and Worship, Monism and Polytheism and Scriptures of Sanatan Dharma.